# WooCommerce Add To Basket button not working

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

Just completing my website with latest version of WP and WooCommerce installed. The issue is that although the add to basket button works on the home page products, it does not work on the individual pages. All it does is refresh the current page with no changes made.

What makes it even stranger is that if the product is a variable product then it DOES work on the individual pages.

I've checked console for errors and no errors appearing. I've disabled all plugins and not found any plugin conflicts. I've tried enabling and disabling AJAX and I've also queried the hosting company if they have any server side caching which they say they do not.

Code for the button on the single product pages is:

```
<button type="submit" name="add-to-cart" 
   value="<?php echo esc_attr( $product->get_id() ); ?>"
   class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt">
<?php echo esc_html( $product->single_add_to_cart_text() ); ?>
</button>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You should share the code in the question, now from my point of view, you just want some  clicks to your website...

Comment: Really hope that was a joke but in case not I've now removed the URL from the question. There was me thinking it would be helpful to have access to the site in question....

Comment: Code for the button on the single product pages is - <button type="submit" name="add-to-cart" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $product->get_id() ); ?>" class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt"><?php echo esc_html( $product->single_add_to_cart_text() ); ?></button>

Comment: Any chance you could edit your code into your question itself? Also you seem to use `submit`, could it be that a `<form action>` is missing on the individual pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if you can add it to cart in the first place like this:

`<a href="?add-to-cart=<?php echo $product->get_id(); ?>">Not Ajax</a>`

Next, rename your template in theme files to stop overriding the original template and see if the button works.

This file is for variable product:

`theme-name/woocommerce/single-product/add-to-cart/variation-add-to-cart-button.php`

This one is for simple product:

`theme-name/woocommerce/single-product/add-to-cart/simple.php`

Check what classes and attributes you need in order to run WC scripts accordingly:

- [variable](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/assets/js/frontend/add-to-cart-variation.js)
- [simple](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/assets/js/frontend/add-to-cart.js)

Comment: Brilliant, thanks Ricky. That code added the product absolutely fine. I will replace the button code with this link code.

Comment: Please note that this is not Ajax call. You must use appropriate selectors in the template if you want to use WC javascript to do the job.